# Nodejs async module which has transaction

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I want to use sqlite database in my project on nodejs. I'm looking for a module for sqlite, which will be operating support for transactions and asynchronous

Comment: Marking to close as "find me a module/tool/library" questions aren't good fits for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is [Knex](http://knexjs.org).  It is a lightweight query builder that supports sqlite, mysql and postgres, has great docs and is under active development.  Knex also supports both promises and callbacks which is a nice touch.

Transactions with Knex are supported through a straightforward Transaction method.  Here is a sample of the syntax:

http://knexjs.org/#Transaction

```
Knex.Transaction(function(t) {

  Knex('books')
    .transacting(t)
    .insert({name: 'Old Books'})
    .then(function(row) {

      return When.all(_.map([
        {title: 'Canterbury Tales'},
        {title: 'Moby Dick'},
        {title: 'Hamlet'}
      ], function(info) {

        info.row_id = row.id;

        // Some validation could take place here.
        return Knex('book').transacting(t).insert(info);

      }));
    })
    .then(t.commit, t.rollback);

}).then(function() {
  console.log('3 new books saved.');
}, function() {
  console.log('Error saving the books.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your best option: https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3

Note that I have no personal experience with it. But it's the most popular/active and supports transactions (https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseexecsql-callback).

A good starting point to find the right node.js modules: https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/sqlite3